# .NET TPL Thread Performance Issue

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, task-parallel-library, semaphore

I am working on the web scraping project and I am using .NET Core 2.0. My customer provided around 1Million Domain and customer asked me to check the domain is active and check the response is OK. My code is below. When I read the domain from the file , I do not have any issues and performance is excellent.

My issue is When I use PLINQ and check the domain is active, it is using only one thread and for 25000 domains it takes around an hour. When I use the Semaphore way, the performance is good and some times, the domain count from the result is not match with Input. For example out of 25000 domains, I am getting the result like 24798 and I do not know where is the remaining 202 domains. How do I improve the performance and What I am missing in the code? Please help. Here I am providing PLINQ and semaphore version of the code.

**Semaphore Version**

```
        var semaphore = new Semaphore(200, 225);
        var allDomains = new List<BsonDocument>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var domain in domainList)
            {
                var cT1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        semaphore.WaitOne();
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref countThreads);
                        var active = IsDomainActive(domain) ? true : false;
                        lock (allDomains) allDomains.Add(
                            new BsonDocument
                            {
                                {"Url", domain},                                    
                                {"Active", active},                                    
                                {"CreatedOn", DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local)},
                                {"UpdatedOn", DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local)}
                            }
                        );
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        semaphore.Release();
                        Interlocked.Decrement(ref countThreads);
                    }
                }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (semaphore != null)
            {
                semaphore.Dispose();
                semaphore = null;
            }
        }
```

**PLINQ Version**

```
var allDomains = (
            from domain in domainList.AsParallel().WithCancellation(cancellationToken).WithDegreeOfParallelism(7).WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
            where IsDomainActive(domain)
            select new BsonDocument
            {
                {"Url", domain},                   
                {"CreatedOn", DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local)},
                {"UpdatedOn", DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local)}
            }).ToList();


 private static bool IsDomainActive(string url)
    {
        var domain = new StringBuilder();
        domain.Append("http://");
        domain.Append(url);
        Console.WriteLine($"IsDomainActive: {url:00} - On Thread " + $"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId:00}. Concurrent: {countThreads}");
        try
        {                               
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(domain.ToString()));             
            request.Timeout = 5000;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            return (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) ? false : true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My PC configuration is below and the issue is appearing in both environment.

1. RAM : 64GB
2. Processor: 8Core
3. Windows 10

My Linux Server Configuration is below

1. RAM: 4GB
2. HDD: 80GB SSD
3. OS: Ubuntu 16.04
4. Processor: 4Core

@edit1

I have updated the code with HttpClient.GetAsync and still the performance is slow and even 1000 domains it takes lot of time.

```
private static async Task<bool> IsDomainActive(string url)
    {
        var domain = new StringBuilder();
        domain.Append("http://");
        domain.Append(url);
        Console.WriteLine("Processing Domain: " + url);
        try
        {
            var sessionId = (new Random()).Next().ToString();
            var netProxy = new WebProxy("<proxyserver>", port);
            login = "<login>";
            password = "<password>";
            netProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Proxy = netProxy,
                UseProxy = true,
            };
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage() {
                RequestUri = new Uri(domain.ToString()),
                Method = HttpMethod.Get
            };
            request.Headers.Add("Timeout","5000");
            request.Headers.Add("UserAgent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2");
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

@edit2
Changed the List<> to Concurrent.

```
private static List<BsonDocument> ProcessFile(ConcurrentBag<string> domains, IProgress<string> progress,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       
        var allDomains = (from domain in domains.AsParallel().WithCancellation(cancellationToken)
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
                .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
            where IsDomainActive(domain).Result
            select new BsonDocument
            {
                        {"Url", domain},                           
                        {"Protocol", "http"},
                        {"CreatedOn", DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local)},
                        {"UpdatedOn", DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local)}
            }).ToList();
        return allDomains;
    }
```

Comment: Why the DegreeOfParallelism is set to 7? Why not use native async calls like HttpClient.GetAsync() ?

Comment: The reason i set DegreeOfParallelism = 7 . My PC configuration is 8 core processor. Once the testing is completed, I plan to change to Environment.ProcessorCount. Because My PC and Server configuration is different.  Where to use HttpClient.GetAsync()?  Please let me know.

Comment: Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You're using not thread safe collection, you cannot use List in parallel code. Do reuse HtpClient instance. You're not waiting for your task in first version of code, thas why it faster.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the code with my question. Because in the comment, it is not allowing me to add the code. :-( not sure why.

Comment: I have changed List<> to ConcurrentBag and I think I am missing something in the way I am using PLINQ. I do not know. I just want ensure that I am heading in the right direction to achieve the result. Sorry for asking again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue and tested the same in linux and works fine. Thank you every one. Instead of semaphore approach and  I have used Parallel.Foreach() and checked the thread creation and validated the result with input. Everything looks good for tomorrow demo.